# Lower bound on the upper incomplete Gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function

The upper incomplete Gamma function is defined as $\Gamma(a,x):=\int_x^\infty t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt$ for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

> I am trying to find an exact, preferably tight, lower bound on $\Gamma(-1,x)$.

I have looked at this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.06384.pdf) and it gives lower bounds for $\Gamma(a,x)$ for $a\geq 1$ in Theorem $1.1$ and for $a<-1$ in Theorem $1.2$. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.10, in particular $\frac{x}{x+2} < x^2 e^x \Gamma ( - 1,x)$ for $x>0$. For large $x$, this is asymptotically sharp.

Comment: $\Gamma(-1,x)$ is an Exponential Integral plus $\frac1{xe^x}$ so finding a bound on the exponential integral only is also an option.

Comment: @Gary Thanks, that was helpful!